# Oracle cannot read picture for SI_StillImage

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have defined folder for user maciek with permissions using sqlplus.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY test AS '\home\oracle\Desktop\test';

SQL> GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY test to maciek;
```

The folder I have created earlier manually.
When I run the following script.

```
DECLARE
OBRAZEK_lob blob;
obrazek_SI si_stillimage;
DANE_PLIKU BFILE := BFILENAME('test','Pojazd.jpg');
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(OBRAZEK_lob, TRUE);
  DBMS_LOB.fileopen(DANE_PLIKU, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);
  DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(OBRAZEK_lob, DANE_PLIKU, DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(DANE_PLIKU));
  DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSE(DANE_PLIKU);
  obrazek_SI :=SI_stillimage(obrazek_lob);
  INSERT INTO foto_oferty_si (idk,nazwa_pliku,opis,obrazek,oferta_id) VALUES(1, 'Pojazd.jpg','Autko', obrazek_si, 1);
  DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(OBRAZEK_lob);
COMMIT;
END;
```

I get the following error message.

```
Error report:
ORA-22285: non-existent directory or file for FILEOPEN operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 805
ORA-06512: at line 7
22285. 00000 -  "non-existent directory or file for %s operation"
*Cause:    Attempted to access a directory that does not exist, or attempted
```

Is it the problem that Oracle doesn't see that folder that I created manually? Shoud the command below create folder pointed at path automatically?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY test AS '\home\oracle\Desktop\test';
```

Comment: Is "\home\oracle\Desktop\test" on your machine or the server where the database is ?

Comment: @KrisRice On Virtual Machine.

Comment: An Oracle Directory points to a directory on the server machine. This can not be used to load from a desktop directory to the server.

Comment: @KrisRice So how to point this directory in Virtual Machine, when I create directory on oracle 11g in virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting but the oracle directory names must be specified in `capital letters`, use `TEST` instead of `test`.

Comment: It helped however, now I get the following error.
file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed

Answer (score 1):

From comments, you are using an Oracle DB inside a VBox and would like to load an image from the host Desktop.

Here's 2 options.

1. Map host directory into the VBox then proceed as your above code but adjust the directory to the mapped in drive.

> ```
> auto-mounted shared folders are mounted into the /media directory, along with the prefix sf_
> ```

Making this example /media/sf_klrice 
Use this in the create directory command.

[image]
VBox Reference: 
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_auto

2. Use SQLcl which allows for JavaScript logic. Instead of PLSQL and Directories the code would look like the snippet below. A more complete write up and example is on my Blog here: http://krisrice.io/2015-10-14-sqlcl-blob-loading-from-file/

   ```
   /*
   *  Function to take in a filename and add or create it to a map
   *  with bind variables
   */
   function addBindToMap(map,bindName,fileName){
        /*  conn is the actual JDBC connection */
        var b = conn.createBlob();

        var out = b.setBinaryStream(1);

        var path = java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(fileName);

        /* slurp the file over to the blob */
        java.nio.file.Files.copy(path, out);
        out.flush();

        if ( map == null ) {
            /* java objects as binds needs a hashmap */
            var HashMap = Java.type("java.util.HashMap");
            map = new HashMap();
        }
        /* put the bind into the map */
        map.put("b",b);
    return map;
   }


   /* File name */
   var file = "/Users/klrice/workspace/raptor_common/10_5.log";

   /* load binds */
   binds = addBindToMap(null,"b",file);

   /* add more binds */
   binds.put("path",file);

   /* exec the insert and pass binds */
   var ret = util.execute("insert into k(path,blob_content,when) values(:path , :b, sysdate)",binds);

   /* print the results */
   sqlcl.setStmt("select path,dbms_lob.getlength(blob_content) from k order by when desc;");

   sqlcl.run();
   ```